# Header keeps expanding beyond browser window

Tags: html, css, header, margin, padding

My new portfolio website should have a header with my name, main navigation and social menu in it. So I made a header with three divs, each one with a width of 33%. My problem is now that as soon as I put position:fixed in there the header keeps expanding beyond the full with. This is only the case when I applied some padding or margin, so that might me the problem, but I have no idea how to fix this issue that's driving me crazy for some hours now.
Maybe some of you might be able to help? Would appreciate it!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">

            <div class="site-title">
                Hello World
            </div>

            <div class="main-menu">
            <ul class="main-menu">
                <a href="work.html"><li>Work</li></a>
                <a href=""><li>Curriculum</li></a>
                <a href="contact.html"><li>Contact</li></a>
            </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="social-menu">
            <ul class="social-menu">
                <a href="#"><li class="fa fa-envelope"></li></a>
                <a href="#"><li class="fa fa-twitter"></li></a>
                <a href="#"><li class="fa fa-dribbble"></li></a>
                <a href="#"><li class="fa fa-youtube-play"></li></a>
                <a href="#"><li class="fa fa-500px"></li></a>
            </ul>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="content">
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>

*{
    margin: 0em;
    padding: 0em;
    border: 0em;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
    color: #333;
}

html{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

container{
    margin: 3em;
    overflow: auto;
}

.content{
    height: 2000px;
}

.container:before,
.container:after {
    content : "";
    display : table;
}
.container:after {
    clear : both;
}

.header{
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100;
    margin: 3em;
    background-color: burlywood;
}

.site-title{
    float:left;
    display: inline-block;
    width: calc(100%/3);
    position: relative;
    background-color: beige;
}

div.main-menu{
    margin:0 auto;
    display: inline-block;
    width: calc(100%/3);
    text-align: center;
    background-color: cadetblue;
}

.main-menu a{
    display: inline-block;
}

div.social-menu{
    float: right;
    width: calc(100%/3);
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: flexbox doesn't answer the question properly (it's a margin problem).

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the margin from .header but I also removed it from .container to be consistent. Amy margin you add will override your container widths even if you have border box running, padding won't.

```css
*{
    margin: 0em;
    padding: 0em;
    border: 0em;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
    color: #333;
}

html{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.container{
   /* margin: 3em; */
  margin: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}

.content{
    height: 2000px;
}

.container:before,
.container:after {
    content : "";
    display : table;
}
.container:after {
    clear : both;
}

.header{
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100;
    /*margin: 3em;*/
    background-color: burlywood;
}

.site-title{
    float:left;
    display: inline-block;
    width: calc(100%/3);
    position: relative;
    background-color: beige;
}

div.main-menu{
    margin:0 auto;
    display: inline-block;
    width: calc(100%/3);
    text-align: center;
    background-color: cadetblue;
}

.main-menu a{
    display: inline-block;
}

div.social-menu{
    float: right;
    width: calc(100%/3);
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">

            <div class="site-title">
                Hello World
            </div>

            <div class="main-menu">
            <ul class="main-menu">
                <a href="work.html"><li>Work</li></a>
                <a href=""><li>Curriculum</li></a>
                <a href="contact.html"><li>Contact</li></a>
            </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="social-menu">
            <ul class="social-menu">
                <a href="#"><li class="fa fa-envelope"></li></a>
                <a href="#"><li class="fa fa-twitter"></li></a>
                <a href="#"><li class="fa fa-dribbble"></li></a>
                <a href="#"><li class="fa fa-youtube-play"></li></a>
                <a href="#"><li class="fa fa-500px"></li></a>
            </ul>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="content">
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer, I tried it now with removing the margins as you suggested, it works with adding a padding to the header (thought I already tried that, but never mind). When adding padding to the whole container the header still doesn't behave properly, not quite sure why.

Comment: Either add padding to the whole container or the individual ones inside it, but not both. Consistency is key here. Do you have a url for what you've tried that you can show?